# how to install HP Laser jet Professional p1108?

Tags: software-installation

How to install HP Laserjet Professional P1108 printer in UBUNTU 14.04 and from where I can get this driver. ?

Comment: Try connect your printer first and then plug its power cable. It should work out the box without driver.Your model is in supported list by this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne

Comment: I have done this process but still printer is not working.

Comment: how did you connect printer with your pc or laptop?

Comment: Via USB with Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

1. Connect your printer with USB.
2. Switch ON printer
3. Open Terminal & run following command.

   `sudo hp-setup`

Enter password & then a dialog box will open. Just follow the instruction to install your printer.

4. Go to System setting --> select **Printers**
   You will see your 'hp-lajerjet' printer.
5. Select your printer. Right Click--> select properties--> select **print test page** to check your printer is working properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

HPLIPS comes preinstalled with ubuntu . So, you dont need additional dirvers for configuring hp printers....
Just plug & play and everything should work..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can check CUPS printer server in your Ubuntu.

Check the printer category and see if there is a driver for it. If not, you can go to the manufacturer website and download it or just use a similar printer driver and I think it can print.